# Show the clip-time in VLC-player, while playing (the time the clip was recorded)

Tags: video, vlc, video-processing

I'm recording some sports footage, and write down some notes, while the recording is going on.

I would like to be able to, as fast as possible, to link my comment to the passage on the video. I record it with a GoPro, so the 1,5 hour longs video gets chopped up to small pieces.

I thought it would be an idea, if VLC could display the actual time of when the footage was take, on screen. In the same manner of this (opening VLC from a command-line with that comment):

```
vlc.exe --sub-filter=marq{marquee=$T/$D" Volume:"$V,size=-2,color=16776960}:marq{marquee=Time:%H:%M:%S" Date:"%d/%m/%Y,color=16776960,size=-2,position=6}
```

That line just shows the current time. I wanted it for example to show something like this:

If the recording was started at `19:39:21`, - then three minutes and 7 seconds into the video, the counter should say `19:42:28`. Is that achievable somehow?

I assumed that VLC was the best/easiest way to achieve it - but if someone else has another or a better idea, then I'm all ears.

Comment: Do you need to see the time every second? Or is it ok if it's shown only when you pause the video? Might be doable with a quick LUA extension

Comment: I would like to see the time all the time. Like a running clock in the top-right of the screen. So I can sit with my written comments on my paper in front of me and see 'Ok - 10 seconds from now, something comes up'. If I would have to pause the video 'all the time', then it would quickly become a nuisance, I'm afraid. :-/

Comment: Ah, I see. Does the text have to be on the video itself? what if it appears as a little window to the side?

Comment: That would be fine, if it was in a video by itself. It would be better if it was on the video - but another windows would be alright. I also thought about making a simple Python-program or something, that opened the video with a timer in another video. But I don't know if there's a better solution.

Comment: So..? what happend to this question?

Comment: It was quite the elaborate answer you came with. I haven't had time to test it. I've never touched LUA in my life - so I have to do a bit of ground work, before I can try and implement what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LUA extension that should do what you need. It'll show the time in the top-right based on a given "start" time. The only thing you'll need to do is set what that start time is. You can adjust the start time at any point and the text should update accordingly:

1. Put the file custom_time.lua in `[VLC DIR]\VLC\lua\extensions`
2. Put the file looper_custom_time.lua in `[VLC DIR]\VLC\lua\intf`
3. run VLC using the command line arguments: `vlc.exe --extraintf=luaintf{intf="looper_custom_time"}`
4. You should see the time in the top-right starting at `12:00:00` and incrementing based on the video playing
5. You can go to `View -> Custom Time` and set what the starting time should be, and the text should update

Let me know if it works!

**custom_time.lua :**

```
function descriptor()
  return {
    title = "Custom Time",
    capabilities = { }
  }
end

function activate()
  window = vlc.dialog("Enter Time")
    textbox = window:add_text_input("HH:MM:SS", 1, 1, 1, 1)
  label = window:add_label("Enter Start Time (24h)", 2, 1, 1, 1)
  button = window:add_button("Set", setStartTime, 1, 2, 2, 1)
end

function deactivate()
end

function meta_changed()
end

function setStartTime()
  vlc.config.set("bookmark10", textbox:get_text())
  vlc.msg.info("[ext_Custom_Time] " .. "Set Start Time to: ".. os.date("%H:%M:%S", globalTimeFinal))
end
```

**looper_custom_time.lua :**

```
-- "looper_custom_time" >> copy the script file into VLC\lua\intf\ folder
-- activate it:
-- vlc.exe --extraintf=luaintf{intf="looper_custom_time"}

function Looper()
   local loops=0 -- counter of loops
   while true do
      if vlc.volume.get() == -256 then break end  -- inspired by syncplay.lua; kills vlc.exe process in Task Manager

      if vlc.playlist.status()=="stopped" then -- no input or stopped input
         loops=loops+1
         Log(loops)
         Sleep(1)
      else -- playing, paused
         if vlc.playlist.status()=="playing" then
            showFinalTime()
            Sleep(1)
         elseif vlc.playlist.status()=="paused" then
            showFinalTime()
            Sleep(0.3)
         else -- ?
            Log("unknown")
            Sleep(1)
         end
      end
   end
end

function getStartTime()
   local pattern = "(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)"
   local startTimeString = vlc.config.get("bookmark10")
   if startTimeString == nil then
      startTimeString = ""
   end

   local hh, mm, ss = startTimeString:match(pattern)
   return os.time({year = 2000, month = 1, day = 1, hour = hh, min = mm, sec = ss})
end

function Log(lm)
   vlc.msg.info("[looper_intf] " .. lm .. os.date(" %H:%M:%S", getStartTime()))
end

function showFinalTime()
   local timePassed = getTimePassed()
   local timeStart = getStartTime()
   local timeFinal = os.date("%H:%M:%S", timeStart + timePassed)
   vlc.osd.message( timeFinal, vlc.osd.channel_register(), "top-right", 1200000)
end

function getTimePassed()
   return vlc.var.get(vlc.object.input(), "time")
end

function Sleep(st) -- seconds
   vlc.misc.mwait(vlc.misc.mdate() + st*1000000)
end

Looper()
```